# Keyup event firing, change event not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a bunch of controls dynamically.

Essentially I am attaching a keyup to the textbox to detect when up/down is pressed in a table to move between cells. I am also watching for when the input field changes, because I then add that control to an array for posting back when the user hits save.

This works when I tab between controls or click from one control to the next. However, If I use the arrow keys as coded to move between fields, the change event does not fire.

My event handling code looks like this:

```
$('input[id^="reo_"]').bind('change', function () {
   rowDetailChange($(this));
});

$('input[id^="reo_"]').bind('keyup', function (e) {
   processKeyUp($(this), e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The change event fires upon focus out, blur and enter with the condition that the content has been altered. This is because the event would fire a great lot elsewise.

Comment: The content is changing. I wouldn't expect the change event to fire without the content changing.

Comment: One would think this is the logical behavior, but it doesn't work this way. If this weren't the case, ajax calls based on the event "change" would be terrible :)

Comment: Sure. I'm after an alternative for me to work though, I don't care about Ajax in this instance as I don't do any ajax magic on change - the change event pushes the field changed to an array that is then processed with the user hits Save.